# The h2 component within the App.js doesn't render dynamically. What can be the issue?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, react-context, createcontext

These are my components that are within the same directory:

```
// App.js
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Nav from "./Nav";
import { AppProvider } from "./context";

export default function App() {
  const [signedIn, setSignedIn] = useState(true);

  return (
    <div className="App my-3">
      <AppProvider>
        <Nav />
        <h2 className="my-2">{signedIn ? "Signed In!" : "Signed Out!"}</h2>
      </AppProvider>
    </div>
  );
}


// Nav.js
import Btn from "./Btn";

const Nav = () => {
  return <Btn />;
};

export default Nav;


// Btn.js
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { useContext } from "react";
import { context } from "./context";

const Btn = () => {
  const [signedIn, setSignedIn] = useContext(context);
  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    setSignedIn((prevState) => !prevState);
  };

  return (
    <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={handleButtonClick}>
      {signedIn ? "Signed In!" : "Signed Out!"}
    </button>
  );
};

export default Btn;


// context.js
import React, { useState } from "react";

const context = React.createContext();

const AppProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [signedIn, setSignedIn] = useState(true);

  return (
    <context.Provider value={[signedIn, setSignedIn]}>
      {children}
    </context.Provider>
  );
};

export { context, AppProvider };
```

This problem arose only when I tried creating a separate context.js file. It works perfectly fine when the code is as follows:

```
// App.js
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Nav from "./Nav";

export const context = React.createContext();

export default function App() {
  const [signedIn, setSignedIn] = useState(true);

  return (
    <div className="App my-3">
      <context.Provider value={[signedIn, setSignedIn]}>
        <Nav />
        <h2 className="my-2">{signedIn ? "Signed In!" : "Signed Out!"}</h2>
      </context.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}


// Btn.js
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { useContext } from "react";
import { context } from "./App";

const Btn = () => {
  const [signedIn, setSignedIn] = useContext(context);
  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    setSignedIn((prevState) => !prevState);
  };

  return (
    <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={handleButtonClick}>
      {signedIn ? "Signed In!" : "Signed Out!"}
    </button>
  );
};

export default Btn;
```

Can you please help me out here? I'm still a beginner to react so I am unsure as to what I should be doing to overcome this error. I tried several methods but none of them seemed to work

Comment: When you seperated context to another file, you are still using the `signedIn` state from `App.js` file, you should be using `signedIn` from `context` since that is the state being updated. It works before because you passed signedIn state from App to context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Components that want to use values from the context have to explicitly say that they want it. You need to wrap your `h2` in another function component and declare that it wants to use the context as below:

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import Btn from "./Btn.js";
import { AppProvider, context } from "./Context";

const H2 = () => {
  const [signedIn] = useContext(context);
  return <h2 className="my-2">{signedIn ? "Signed In!" : "Signed Out!"}</h2>;
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App my-3">
      <AppProvider>
        <Btn />
        <H2 />
      </AppProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

#### Demo:

[image: Edit clever-lumiere-mnsrrd]